# Download/Export json file on mac OS with Angular 5

Tags: json, angular, macos

I tried to download a json object on my device "mac os" using the code below. The result was show the json body on the browser, although it works with other os "android, windows".

Is there any alternative solution?

```
function downloadJsonFile(fileName, jsonObject) {
    let fileContents = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
    let data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(fileContents);
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = 'data:' + data;
    a.download = fileName + '.json';
    a.click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

DEMO ----> [Download Json](https://stackblitz.com/edit/downloadjson)

```
  download(strData, strFileName, strMimeType) {

    strData = JSON.stringify(strData);
    var D = document,
      A = arguments,
      a = D.createElement("a"),
      n = A[1];
    a.href = "data:" + strMimeType + "charset=utf-8," + (strData);
    if ('download' in a) {
      a.setAttribute("download", n);
      a.innerHTML = "downloading...";
      D.body.appendChild(a);
      setTimeout(function () {
        var e = D.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        a.dispatchEvent(e);
        D.body.removeChild(a);
      }, 66);
      return true;
    }; 
    var f = D.createElement("iframe");
    D.body.appendChild(f);
    f.src = "data:" + (A[2] ? A[2] : "application/octet-stream") + (window.btoa ? ";base64" : "") + "," + (strData);
    setTimeout(function () {
      D.body.removeChild(f);
    }, 333);
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: in fact no error ! , just doesn't respond  as required , it seems like i did NO THING ! that's weird .

Comment: i am trying to open my website by using Ipad ,it works on other devices properly

Comment: Yes , now it works thanks !! 
 , but the problem is that it was saved as unknown , not with the expected filename

Comment: pass filename in variable strFileName

Comment: Accept and Vote up if solution helped.

Comment: it seems good , but it is not completed , because cant rename the file name that should be downloaded .